# information not available, No symbols loaded for .dll

Tags: automation, com, invoke, idispatch

I applied Invoke to use object of an application in C++ but an error occurred.
error:information not available, No symbols loaded for GPNSAutomation.dll
My codes is :

```
 ::CLSIDFromProgID(OLESTR("SGNSAutomation.SGNSApplication"), &clsid);
IID iid;
  HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, 
  IID_IDispatch, (LPVOID*)&pWMPDispatch);
  IDispatch * pdisp = (IDispatch *)NULL;
  DISPID dispid;
  DISPPARAMS  params= {NULL,NULL,0,0};
 params.cArgs =1;
  OLECHAR * Name = OLESTR("importCase");
 HRESULT hresult =pWMPDispatch->GetIDsOfNames(IID_NULL, 
     &Name,1,LOCALE_SYSTEM_DEFAULT,&dispid);
  hresult =pWMPDispatch->Invoke(dispid, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, 
            DISPATCH_METHOD, &params, NULL, NULL,
                          NULL);  

_ASSERT(hr==S_OK);
```

Comment: It is not an error, merely a notification from the debugger that it could not locate the PDB for the file.  Use Debug > Windows > Modules, right-click the DLL and select "Symbol Load Information".  It shows you where it looked.  If you did not create this DLL yourself, the normal case for any COM component, then this is entirely normal.